# AngularJS: Where to store my CSS related to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Assume that you want to create a directive in AngularJS that requires an external CSS file.

Are there any best practices on where to store the directive's CSS content?

Edit : I am after a solution that in order to copy my directive to another anguarljs app, I will only need to copy the directive code and not have to go over all my CSS.

In the case where there is a templateUrl parameter in the directive, I guess the best place to put the directive's CSS is the HTML template, or not?

Comment: Css can be stored where you keep all your css files itself like a content folder. you can follow best practices to structure your Angular JS related files though.

Comment: I am after a solution that in order to copy my directive to another anguarljs app, I will only need to copy the directive code and not have to go over all my CSS.

Comment: Its clear now, better you edit your question for better clarity then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep the html template in a separate file I would suggest you keep the css separately too. In this case you could use a tool like [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to bring all those separate directive css together

If the html template is inside the directives definition the best choice would be to keep the css as a style tag provided that the style sheet is a must have and is as malleable as possible